# Unable to place the buttons in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing difficulty in placing buttons like **AC** and **backspace** in the provided Jetpack Compose code. I have attached a screenshot of the current preview [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztvVX.png) and an image of the desired design [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrSJw.png).

```
@Composable
fun UnitConverter(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier
            .background(Color(0xFF252323))
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Column() {
            Row {
                CalculatorButton(text = "7", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = "8", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = "9", onClick = {})
             }
            Row {
                CalculatorButton(text = "4", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = "5", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = "6", onClick = {})
            }
            Row {
                CalculatorButton(text = "1", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = "2", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = "3", onClick = {})
            }
            Row {
                CalculatorButton(text = "C", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = "0", onClick = {})
                CalculatorButton(text = ".", onClick = {})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use 4 columns, the first three will contain four rows (1,2....0, C & dot) inside, the last column will have two (AC, backspace). And set `Modifier.weight(1f)` to each item.